# Command history for user never using interactive shell

Tags: command-line, shell, command-history

Can I view the history of a non-interactive user, for example, httpd?  Hopefully, the answer is not specific to the shell used.  I'm looking for history that could be in either bash or dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command history generally only applies to interactive shell use. The activity history of other programs may be recorded in log files which you can find in places like /var/log and /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2. The existence of a pseudo-user account called httpd doesn't mean that account ever runs any shell at all.